# How can I remove specific lines from each datablock?

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have repeating dataset which looks like

```
700
block1
1  A  A  A
2  B  B  B
C  3  4  5 
D  6  8 10
....
FF DD 22 11 
700
block2
1  B  B  B
C  D  F  Q
....
```

The file is made up of 100 data blocks, and each data block have 702 lines. The first line of each data block is the number of data (=700), and second line of each data block is the number of data block.

Here, I hope to remove 3rd ~ 100th line from every data block (this will remove 98 lines), left only 101th ~ 700th line in each data block. Is there any way to do this in sed or grep? Do I need to use for loop?

I know how to remove lines with specific patter using grep -v and sed, but I couldn't find how to delete multiple lines inside each data block.

Comment: What about the 701st and 702nd  lines? Do you want to keep the "700" and the "block1" or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^700$/,+1p;//,+99d' file
```

Print the lines you want and delete the lines you don't.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
awk '(NR % 702) < 3; (NR % 702) > 100' file > new_file
```

`NR`: current record number in the total input stream (line number)

`%`: modulo operation